# Ubuntu crashing after login window

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash

Below is the screenshot of ubuntu 12.04 crashing at login screen.

I have googled alot for the solution but hardly anything seems to work.

If i try to use telnet localhost this is what it says

[image]

Comment: Try to specify if you is a new system installation, if it is on a virtual machine, if before was working. What did you change. If you are able to start is [single user mode](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grub-boot-into-single-user-mode/) and what said `dmesg`... how it is now it's too generic

Comment: @Hastur Its not a new installation.It wass working for 3 months annd now started giving problem. I am able to login through putty and I can access all content. When i try to use telnet command . It says host network not found.

Comment: If you want that someone can help you write more information and [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/782813/edit) your post: it's too generic so. It's a linux in a virtual machine under windows? It's a pure linux installation? what is the _selected_ output of `dmesg`? (maybe in the last lines of `dmesg` there is the reason of the crash. (`dmesg | grep rror` and `dmesg | grep arning` can give hints to you.  `dmesg | less` you can read all the log)